# How to prevent "unvalidated redirects"?

Tags: security, redirect

I'm trying to harden a Joomla site (v3.9.13).

The security team have raised an issue regarding redirects. They require that there should be a whitelist of addresses to which the website can redirect.

Is this a known issue? And is there a suggested solution?

TIA

Comment: Is this your clients 'security team' ? And are you meaning redirects away from your site or into your site? Can you maybe expand on what scenarios they might be talking about.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply, @Irata. I don't have any more useful information to add, unfortunately. And it's no longer an issue for the client.

Answer (score 1):

If you mean that you want to **harden** the **HTTP security headers** of your Joomla site, then you can install + configure a **HttpHeader Plugin**: https://github.com/zero-24/plg_system_httpheader

It has an option to configure the **HTTP Content-Security-Policy** in which you can whitelist which external resources like JavaScript may be loaded on your site by your visitor's browser.

PS: The future Joomla 4 will have that plugin in the core.